# ros::serialization::OStream

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any standard way of converting ros::serialization::OStream to any standard format like std::string or std::stringstream?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260197/ros::serialization::ostream/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I suggest you to take a look to the way it is done in tool_topics:ShapeShifter

http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/topic_tools/html/shape__shifter_8h_source.html

I expect the function you want to write to look like this

```
void copyToString(ros::serialization::OStream& stream, std::string& output)
{
   output.resize( stream.getLength()  );
   memcpy(stream.getData(),  &output[0], stream.getLength());
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-04-25**:
Actually I would like to send the ros::serialization::OStream over a boost::asio::socket, I'm not sure how can I send it through a boost::socket or do I need to transform it in another format...